# Windows 10 touchpad doesn't work after I use my keyboard for about 3 seconds

Tags: mouse

Whenever I type on my keyboard it takes about 3 seconds before my touchpad will actually work to make my mouse cursor move. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laptops will often have a setting to detect if your palm is resting on the trackpad and will temporarily disable it. As mentioned below by [Ben](https://superuser.com/users/33595/ben-richards), there is a native Windows 10 setting for this under:

- Settings
- Devices
- Mouse & touchpad

[image]

---

You can also check in the Control Panel under Mouse (or possibly TrackPad) for more settings.

For example, Lenovo laptops typically configure this through the Synaptics Control Panel:

- Control Panel
- Mouse
- ThinkPad
- Settings
- Advanced

[image]

Comment: The OS version wasn't specified, but Windows (at least Windows 10) has this setting built-in to their mouse Settings app screen, if I recall correctly, as well. So it would be good to check both the OS and any driver-specific settings app.

Comment: @BenRichards The title says Windows 10, and you are right.

Comment: Perfect! Fixed! I probably would have eventually figured it out, I just haven't felt like messing with my settings too deeply. But I'm good to go! Ty again.

Comment: @user560338 Please mark the answer as accepted (the checkmark under it) then.